Why do my motors run slowly and then stop when powered by two 9V batteries in parallel through an L298n motor driver with a NodeMCU ESP8266?
I am currently working on a project that involves controlling four dual-shaft DC geared motors (the yellow ones.) I am controlling them with an L298N motor driver through a NodeMCU ESP-8266. I have connected the D0-D3 pins from the NodeMCU to the In1-In4 pins of the module for communication. The NodeMCU is powered through the micro USB, but the ground is shared with the L298N module. The L298N module is powered by two 9V batteries in parallel, but the motor is not running as intended. Initially, it runs very slowly.  After a few minutes, it tends to stop. When  I measure the input from the battery in the module, they keep on jumping from 3V to 5.5V, but the battery when measured externally gives 9V. Can anyone help me with it?

What help do you need? If 9V batteries can't power it, use something more powerful. Which motor it is, do you have the specs sheet for it, and how much current it needs?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

but the battery when measured externally gives 9V ... probably not when the motor is trying to run

If the voltage from the battery drops from 9V to 3V when the motors are running, then the battery is simply not up to the task.
You are trying to drive four motors at the same time from two 9V batteries.  If your motors are like these then that would be 800mA of current from those two batteries.  9V batteries are not made for high current.
You need a better power source for your motors.  Try running a single motor and see if it does better by itself than when trying to run four motors.
If a single motor doesn't run well, then your batteries may have been run down by your attempts with four motors - use new batteries.  You may also be using motors that draw more current than the ones I found - it is better to include a link to your equipment when you post a question.

Thank you for your clarification

@arun The expected way to thank is to accept the answer, comments are not for that. You might want to take the [tour] and to read some pages of the [help].
